# Mongoose: check if object is mongoose object

Tags: mongoose

anyone know what the simplest way to check whether an object is a mongoose object? 
Am I just best checking if toObject() is defined or is there a more efficient way.
many thanks

Answer (score 37):

You can check the object's prototype via the `instanceof` operator to confirm it's an instance of your mongoose model.  Using the example schema from [mongoosejs.com](http://mongoosejs.com/):

```
if (obj instanceof Cat) {
    // yes, it's a mongoose Cat model object
    ...
}
```

Comment: Nice!  e.g. this.message = object instanceof Message ? object : new Message(object);

Answer (score 22):

I'm using this

```
if (object.constructor.name === 'model') {
  // object is mongoose object
}
```

Comment: 'model' is a very generic name.

Comment: My solution is a bit more strict `object.constructor.collection.name !== 'SCHEMA_NAME'`

Answer (score 9):

My preferred way to determine if an object is a Mongoose model is almost as simple as the above, but not quite:

```
function isModel(obj) {
    obj = obj || {}
    return obj.prototype instanceof mongoose.Model
}
```

In the context where I use this, I don't want to get undefined back, but do need to verify that I haven't gotten a "3" or some such oddball value where I expect a model.

Of course, after thinking further about this, there's more than one way to be a "Mongoose object." I've sometimes mistaken a DTO for a Mongoose model and then misused it later, hence my test above...but if I just needed to verify that something is an instance, but for some reason could not know the instance type, I would do something like what Lukasz did above and look at the constructor base.

Comment: Accessing `obj.prototype` doesn't work in current node.js implementations (not TypeScript). Use this check instead: `Object.getPrototypeOf(object) instanceof mongoose.Model`

Answer (score 4):

Another simple way:

```
const isMongooseModel = (object instanceof Mongoose.Model);
```

Comment: -1 due to ambiguous `object` usage, what is it now? [Tony A.T. Mendina's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52300109/250453) is more appropriate since it uses `prototype` to check if instance of `Mongoose.Model` or not.

Answer (score 3):

One way to determine is if you do a

```
if (data.toObject)
```

it will return a Function statement if its true, will return undefined if it isn't;

Answer (score 2):

The follwing for me in the case of checking when an ObjectID is a populated object or just an ObjectID:

```
if (object._id.constructor.name === 'ObjectID') {
    // Not a populated object, only its ID
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To check whether `obj` is a Mongoose object, use this snippet:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

function checkIfMongooseObject(obj) {
  return _.get(obj, 'constructor.base') instanceof mongoose.Mongoose;
}
```

Contrary to other solutions provided, this one is safe - it will never fail regardless type of `obj` (be it even String or Int).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

function isMongoModel(yourObject){

    return yourObject.hasOwnProperty('schema') && yourObject.schema instanceof mongoose.Schema;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This, if you want to make sure it's the model you expect.

`dog.constructor.modelName === 'Dog'`

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with typescript and using typescript imports then this helps

```js
import { Mongoose } from 'mongoose';

...
const isMongooseModel = (object instanceof Mongoose.prototype.Model); // true if object is of type Model
const isMongooseDocument = (object instanceof Mongoose.prototype.Document); // true if object is of type Document
const isMongooseQuery = (object instanceof Mongoose.prototype.Query); // true if object is of type Query
```