# insert many don’t working in mongo DB why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to insert many in mongoDB using mongoose’s .it only save `one collection` only why 
Here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-solomon-o91wp

I save like that

```
app.get("/saveData", async () => {
  try {
    const data = [
      {
        empid: "test123",
        date: "19-Jul-2019"
      },
      {
        empid: "test13",
        date: "18-Jul-2019"
      },

      {
        empid: "test13",
        date: "11-Jul-2019"
      }
    ];
    console.log("before save");
    let saveBlog = await BlogPostModel.collection.insertMany(data, {
      checkKeys: false
    }); //when fail its goes to catch
    console.log(saveBlog); //when success it print.
    console.log("saveBlog save");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

**try to fetch data like that**

```
app.get("/filter", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let filterBlog = await BlogPostModel.find({});
    //when fail its goes to catch
    console.log(filterBlog); //when success it print.
    res.send(filterBlog);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

**showing only one document**

[image]

Comment: may be try with `insert()` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#db-collection-insert

Comment: but I have multiple documents

Comment: Check the database. The documents are there.

Comment: @AlexBlex `only one` document is saved

Comment: see my image..!!

Comment: yeah, you can try with insert, and the array of your documents. even if you have multiple

Comment: What does `saveBlog.insertedCount` show you right after `insertMany()`? Or as mentioned previously `Model.collection.insert(docsArray, options, callback)` should work.

Comment: @SaikatChakrabortty could you please update my codeshandbox link

Comment: `insert` also add one `item` ..can we use mongoos here

Comment: Where did you this image from? Look at the database with mongo shell, compas, robomongo or any other client. Enable mongo [profiler](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/), trigger the insert, find the log entry and add it to the question.

Comment: @AlexBlex I am using `online` https://mlab.com/databases/studentnsit/collections/blogposts?q=&f=&s=&pageNum=0&pageSize=10

Comment: @AlexBlex i am online `mlab`..you can also check `/filter` service to check save document

Comment: @user944513 i have added one answer , using your database only. if you think it answers your question, i would love if you mark it as a correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here as i suspected, there is one more index present in the collection you created i.e `blogposts`. the index is `id` [key `id` name `id_1`]. 
Here is your whole project, i have added in glitch.

[Demo](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/dramatic-archaeopteryx?path=server.js:64:17)

and here i also have added one api [`/indexes`](https://dramatic-archaeopteryx.glitch.me/indexes) , this retrieves all indexes of the collection. by default `_id` should be there, additional indexes are added after. so here you can see `id`, which needs to be unique.

i have made few more changes to your code.

The route [`/saveData`](https://dramatic-archaeopteryx.glitch.me/saveData) now able to insert records. and it has the field called `id` which is unique.

but, the old route that is now at `/saveData_old`, which will give you error as there are no keys that represents this index key [`id`]. [also after inserting one, it will have `id` null and rest will fail, just causing duplicate ]

now you can either use `id` key with unique values, or if you don't need you can also drop the index as well. you can find an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014548/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-drop-indexes-using-mongoose) for how to drop index.