# Mongo not allowing save to duplicate data, even after specifying as not unique

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have specified `firstname` and `lastname` MongoDB fields to **not** be unique, but i am still running into an issue that I cannot say non-unique firstnames and lastnames.

How do I specify to MongoDB it is okay to have duplicate of `firstname` and `lastname`?

```
extend type Mutation {
    signUp(
      firstname: String!
      lastname: String!
      email: String!
      password: String!
    ): Token!

...

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
      validate: [isEmail, 'Not a valid email'],
    },
    firstname: {
      type: String,
      unique: false
    },
    lastname: {
      type: String,
      unique: false
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      minlength: 7,
      maxlength: 42,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  },
);
```

Error:

```
E11000 duplicate key error collection: testDb.users index: firstname_1 dup key: { firstname: "Test" }
```

Comment: You need to drop `users` collection and run your app. Seems you have created with unique index and now you are trying to undo it

Comment: im not sure how you spotted that (or how i would have) but this did work right now. i dropped my testDB and all worked..strange

Answer (score 1):

Since you've created unique index on your collection as it says `firstname_1 dup key: { firstname: "Test" }` then you need to drop it first before inserting duplicate documents. In general you would mention `unique:true` on a field in mongoose schema in order to create an unique index from code for the first time, rather than executing DB commands manually, anyway in actual terms indexes are created on database. So changing code doesn't drop existing indexes on database. Either you've to run [dropIndex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/index.html) manually on DB or else through mongoose try this [drop-indexes-using-mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014548/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-drop-indexes-using-mongoose) :

```
db.users.dropIndex( "firstname_1" )
```

Answer (score 1):

`unique: false` doesn't force mongoose to drop your particular indexes. As you already have indexes created in database, you should remove them either using mongo shell manually or programmatically.

In mongo shell it will look like

```
db.users.dropIndex('firstname_1');
db.users.dropIndex('lastname_1');
```

But before doing this it's better to double-check precise index names, and for this we have the following command

```
db.users.getIndexes();
```