# Mongoose MongoError : 11000

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I sent a create post signal through Postman. a once time, the post signal was a successfully. but next time it was failed . error message is like this.

```
Error creating new record : {
  "driver": true,
  "name": "MongoError",
  "index": 0,
  "code": 11000,
  "keyPattern": {
    "RoutineParts.userId": 1
  },
  "keyValue": {
    "RoutineParts.userId": null
  }
}
```

i cant understand the error message,
my post code and user model code is like that ,

```
// it's post code. 

router.post('/',(req,res)=>{
    const newRecord = User ({
        username : req.body.username,
        email : req.body.email,
        password : req.body.password
    })

    newRecord.save((err,docs)=>{
        if(!err) {
            res.send(docs)
        }else {
            console.log('Error creating new record : ' + JSON.stringify(err,undefined,2))
        }
    })
})

// it's user model
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        username : {type:String},
        email: { type: String, required: true},
        password: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
        created_at : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        updated_at : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    }
)

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = { User }
```

i can't understand. In fact 'RoutineParts' is a one of model, but i didn't write user's documents. and, controller path is corrected in app.js

how can i solve it?

it's RoutineParts model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        routine_name : {type:String},
        userId : { type: String, required: true},
        exercise_name : { type: String},
        order : { type: Number},
    }
)

const RoutineParts = mongoose.model('RoutineParts', userSchema);

module.exports = { RoutineParts }
```

and it's app.js contents

```
// Connecting data to the MongoDB through Mongoose
require('./db')

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const PORT = 5000
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const userRoute = require('./controller/user')
const routineRoute = require('./controller/routine')
const RP_Route = require('./controller/routineParts')
const EX_Route = require('./controller/excersise')

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.status(201).send("<h1>Hey guys! Hello World !!</h1>");
  });

app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log(`start express server on port ${PORT}`);
  });

app.use('/Users', userRoute)
app.use('/Routine', routineRoute)
app.use('/Excersise', EX_Route)
app.use('/RoutineParts', RP_Route)
```

Comment: Show the `RoutineParts` model too?

Comment: add new in front of User : `const newRecord = new User`

Comment: @AKX yes.  RoutineParts is one of model

Comment: Also, not sure what the error code is about. 11000 is for duplicate documents but I can not find it in docs.

Comment: @Tushar Shahi Aaaa Thanks i will try now.

Comment: @Tushar Shahi i m just tried `const newRecord = new User` . but result is same..

Comment: @Loolii looks like the error is about another model `RoutinePart` . Can you include more code - it doesn't seem the error comes from the code you shared.

Comment: @Pascal Lamers Okay . I will :)

Comment: Why do you need `unique` `true` for `userid` inside RoutineParts Schema ? Try removing it for testing and start again.

Comment: @Pascal Lamers hmm it's same.. thank you for opinion :)

Comment: There must be something you're not telling us / showing us. How does your file structure look like ? Are there any documents already in MongoDB ? I think MongoDB now already indexed the userid field ... try dropping the collection from mongodb and start again. Clearly at somepoint you are trying to create a `RoutinePart` which only worked for the first time, after that it shows you the Duplicate Key error.

Comment: @Pascal Lamers Hmm.. well i didn't install mongodb in npm. but i installed moongose
as tutorial lecture. hmmm Okay i will try. thanks !!

Comment: Yes but you connected to a mongodb database right ? otherwise where would you store your data ? `mongoose` is just a nodejs driver to interact with mongodb .

Comment: @Pascal Lamers of course i did :)  database was connected. so i saw my database by compas. I was succeeded in first trial.  :)  now, anyway its well by your help.
but i dont know why happened the error.. i need to read your advised again..

Comment: I'd like to help but this conversation doesn't go anywhere. Do you have a minimal reproducible example somewhere on github ?

Comment: @Pascal Lamers Hmm okay.  i m still cant understand this error.. just i dropped 'users' collection by your advised. i will upload my git repository.

Comment: @PascalLamers it's my git repository, https://github.com/LeeGeonwoo22/only3days-server.git. i m just uploaded. truly , it's work well in my local. but i didn't modified in code.. just deleted collection by your advised.

Comment: Thanks i ll take look ...

Comment: Yo dude it's private :D

Comment: @PascalLamers Ahhh ooopsss now you can access the git repository. i just invited you :)

Comment: @Loolii Please take a look at my answer 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### What's going on

I took a look at your full code. The only real problem, which also fits with the error message you are seeing, is the following :

- In your `./models/routineParts.js` you've set a `unique` field. In your case `userid`. E.g. if your create a new `routineParts` document with `userid` "`AAA`" you **can not** create another document with the same `userid` "`AAA`". In short this means, every user can only create 1 single `routineParts` document. 
  The first time you did a `POST` request to your route `localhost:5000/RoutineParts` it created the first `routineParts` document. After that, every request will fail, because it already created 1 `routineParts` document. ( Read here about [unique index with mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematypeoptions_SchemaTypeOptions-unique) ) 
  See your `./controller/routineParts.js` . If you try to do the same request with a different `userid` it should work.

### How to fix

- **1** : Remove `unique: true` from your `./models/routineParts` Schema.
- **2** : ⚡ Drop the index . Mongoose most-likey already registered this index and you have to drop it specifically. Otherwise it will always treat the `userid` field as `unique`.
- **3** : You are still in development, so it shouldn't hurt to also drop the `RoutineParts` collection.
- **4** : Restart the app and try to hit the `POST localhost:5000/RoutineParts` endpoint a couple of times. You now should be able to create multiple `routineParts` documents under the same user.

#### How to drop the index

That's a different story. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014548/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-drop-indexes-using-mongoose) should help you with that. They are also using mongoose. If your are using the latest version of `mongoose` there is a method called [`cleanIndexes`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014548/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-drop-indexes-using-mongoose). Use this method after you've removed the `unique:true` from your model.

Answer (score 1):

For solve this isuse you must remove index duplicate email_1 from index menu [image]